# What do those +/- mean if linux job in background finishes (started with &)

Tags: linux, bash

If I start a process with an ampersand (`&`) at the end, it'll be forked to background. When it finishes, I get an output similar to

```
[1]+  Fertig   my_script
```

I have a localized distribution, but this shouldn't matter.

What I see is the job ID in square brackets followed by a plus (`+`).

If I have multiple jobs started in parallel, I get

```
[1]-  Fertig   my_script
[2]+  Fertig   my_script
```

Now I have a minus (`-`) for the fist job and a plus (`+`) for the second one.

I wonder, what those `+`/`-` mean.

Couldn't find any answer using internet search engines.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> In output pertaining to jobs (e.g., the output of the `jobs` command), the current job is always flagged with a `+`, and the previous job with a `-`.

That is, the job flagged with a `+` is the one that was sent to the background last.

It is also the one that will be brought into the foreground when `fg` is used without arguments:

```
$ /tmp/script &
[1] 9871
$ /tmp/script2 &
[2] 9876
$ /tmp/script3 &
[3] 9881
$ /tmp/script4 &
[4] 9886
$ jobs
[1]   Running                 /tmp/script &
[2]   Running                 /tmp/script2 &
[3]-  Running                 /tmp/script3 &
[4]+  Running                 /tmp/script4 &
$ fg
/tmp/script4
```

The job flagged with a `-` was sent to the background second last. Other background jobs are not flagged.

Comment: So, the + is useful in saying what the fg/bg commands will do, but is the - useful for anything?

Comment: @tsbertalan I agree, I can't see any use for it. I find it confusing, too, I'd rather expect the - to identify the job sent *first* to the background, but maybe it's just me...

Comment: I sometimes see two pluses or two minuses there. Does not really fit the 'last' or 'current' definition. That's bash 4.3.42.

Comment: @tsbertalan I do Ctrl+Z, then `fg -` to switch between two jobs. The minus sign comes in handy.